# Which of the following are subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers

I was working on subspace and found a problem that check following are subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^3(\Bbb{R})$ or not.

1) W = {($a^5$,0,0) : a∈$\Bbb{R}$}

2) U = {($a^2$,0,0) : a∈$\Bbb{R}$}

My Attempt : I just use the formal one step test of subspace. Let ($x^5$,0,0),($y^5$,0,0) in W and α, β∈$\Bbb{R}$

α($x^5$,0,0)+β($y^5$,0,0) = (α$x^5$+β$y^5$,0,0) and orally I declared that it is not a subspace. But after thinking on the property that Real numbers are closed under addition and multiplication so,

α$x^5$+β$y^5$ will be a Real number there should exist a real number z (say) such that α$x^5$+β$y^5$ = $z^5$ finally it's become subspace.

But again  i confused when i thought about Transcendental numbers Like π. I stuck here whether the 5th root of π exist or not.
Help me here.
For U,  I declared by giving the argument that there is no real number such that $x^2$=-1. U is not subspace.
Thanks

Comment: Well, there is $\sqrt[5]{\pi}\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Nikita Evseev : Can we generally say that W={(a^p,0,0) : a∈R, p is odd prime} is subspace?

Comment: @Chiranjeev Yes, we can.

Comment: @hamid kamali : your statement is not right as √4=+2,-2

Comment: @Nikita Evseev : Thanks

Comment: every positive real number, has a unique positive $n$-th root. @Chiranjeev thank you for your guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to check if a nonempty subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace is the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). This states that $S$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $u+\lambda v\in S$ whenever $u,v\in S$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Let's prove that 
$$
W=\{(a^5,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3:a\in\Bbb R\}
$$
is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ using the one-step vector subspace test. Note that $W\neq\varnothing$ since $(0,0,0)\in W$.

Let $(a^5,0,0),(b^5,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Let $c=\left(a^5+\lambda b^5\right)^{1/5}$. Then
$$
(a^5,0,0)+\lambda(b^5,0,0)
= \left(a^5+\lambda b^5,0,0\right)
= \left(c^5,0,0\right)\in S
$$
Hence $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^5$.

*Extra Credit.* Is 
$$
W=\{(a^6,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3:a\in\Bbb R\}
$$
a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?